# How to retrieve private key information when we are creating azure vm from terraform?

Tags: centos, azure, terraform

I have created a linux centos machine on azure cloud using terraform.

I tried to see the content of private key so I can connect later using output variable.

But, I got error as I need to set it as sensitive and I did the same and the outputs is shown as below.

Apply complete! Resources: 15 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

```
tls_private_key = <sensitive>
```

How to get the private key content then?
My terraform files [link](https://github.com/thunderbirds-2021/terraform_testing)

It seems I can retrieve that from state file but it has all the lines kept with \n and I need to manually replace all of them one by one with new line from editor like vscode.

Any other suugestions?

Answer (score 0):

refer ：https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-linux-virtual-machine-with-infrastructure

1. terraform output -raw tls_private_key > id_rsa
2. terraform output public_ip_address
3. ssh -i id_rsa azureuser@<public_ip_address>